# Why if statement in Shopify-Liquid is not working as expected?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm working with `array of array` in `shopify-liquid` and when i am trying to use the if statement to get only records where `charge[2] > 0` but somehow its including the records where `charge[2] = 0` and i'm not able to understand why is it happening.

```
{% assign array_of_arrays = [["0.0","5.0","0.0"],["0.0","6.6","8.8"],["0.0","9.9","1.1"]] %}


{%- for header in array_of_arrays -%}
  {%- for charge in header[-1] -%}
    {% if charge[2] > 0 %}
       "this is it!!"
    {% endif%}
  {%- endfor -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Can anyone please help me understand where i'm making the mistake?

Comment: It's more or less impossible to divine what is happening here without seeing the data. Computers are also fairly reliable in regards to evaluating if conditions, if the condition `charge[2] > 0` is said to be true, it's almost certainly because it is true. You could debug by displaying the content of `charge[2]` instead of `"this is it!!"`.

Comment: hello @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier yes i have tried that, the issue is that its printing all the values of charge[2] even though only for 3 out of 10 records fulfill the logic. Could this be happening because of data -type of charge[2] because i am having trouble checking its data-type and maybe its string?

Comment: "[...] all the values of charge[2]" if charge[2] is not an integer, the comparison will almost certainly not yield what you expect. If you want to compare every individual values in charge[2], you will need to iterate over them like the other for blocks. Maybe something like `{%- for individualCharge in charge[2] -%}`

Comment: that's indeed the case!! so the charge[2] values are of type float like 20.00,  19.77, 25.8829. so what's the solution here? how can i make sure this condition works?

Comment: Please see my updated comment from earlier, you would need to loop over the charge[2] values with another for block, then check the condition on `individualCharge` inside that loop.

Comment: Could you include some code that initializes `array_of_arrays` so there's a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: hello @toastifer i have added a sample test data. please have a look

Comment: @toastifer i actually found a way to resolve this issue. check my answer. i hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to get this sorted by using a small trick. Before, if sattement i convereted the string to a float and hence it worked.

```
{%- for header in array_of_arrays -%}
   {%- for charge in header[-1] -%}
     {%- assign char_2 = charge[2] | replace: ',' '.' | string.to_float -%}
     {% if char_2 > 0 %}
       charge: {{}} {{charge}} {{}}
     {% endif%}
   {%- endfor -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

I hope it helps.